# Apostrophe after Acronym that ends in "S"

Tags: abbreviations, apostrophe, acronyms

What are the rules for using apostrophes after an acronym that ends in the letter "S"?

For instance, if I have a pretend product called Fast Ice Cream System, or FICS, which delivers ice cream very quickly to wherever you are, I could:

- Have more than one FICS (would this be written as FICSs, FICS', FICS'S or FICSS)
- Have a component of the FICS (this would be "the FCIS's flux capacitor)

Is there an appropriate English style guide? I can't imagine this is new territory.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth my question is specifically about abbreviations that end in S, it’s not clear to me if the rules differ

Comment: From [Pain in the English](https://painintheenglish.com/case/333): << This rule is exactly the same when the acronym in question ends in an S. So you have one ACS, and a thing belonging to it is the ACS's thing. Or you have additional ACSs, and something belonging to the ACSs is the ACSs' thing. ... speedwell2 >> However, the majority view is that abbreviations not pronounced as if single words are initialisms, not acronyms. Thus CIA (and doubtless FICS) is an initialism, NASA (like radar) an acronym